# How many bits are specified for real and imaginary parts in complex class of c++

Tags: c++, bit

I am using complex class for float numbers, can anyone tell me exactly how many bits or bytes are allocated to the real and imaginary part of data. Also what is the format in which data is saved i.e RIRIRI or RRRIII

Comment: `std::complex<T>` is precisely a pair of two `T`s, one for the real and one for the imaginary part.

Comment: One could use `sizeof`. Or simply google for `std::complex` and check the stream operators' documentation, eg [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_ltltgtgt)

Comment: Layout?  Encapsulation is one of those fundamental C++ goals for classes.  Because this information is encapsulated, the layout can be changed for any reason, perhaps even to improve performance.  Furthermore, this improvement can occur at any time, even the next release, with no impact to how it is used.

Comment: Use **sizeof** operator to know the size

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass `std::complex<float>` directly to `std::numeric_limits<std::complex<float>>`, but you can check `std::numeric_limits<float>`. That gives the numerical properties of the real and imaginary parts.